# Service restarts after app closes android

Tags: android, service

I created a simple app where i simply put thread to sleep and count from 1 to 20 and display on GUI. Everything works fine on pause and resume but whenever i close the app and restart, the application restarts.

Is this normal? Is there a way to resume my counting from when it was closed?
Any help is appreciated.

Regards
Sagar

Comment: Try saving the value in SharedPreferences

Comment: If you force stop your app and restart it, it must be restarts all state. That is certainly the case because your thread attached on your application though you use service to start your thread separated from your activity. If you want to resume the counter, you should store that value persistently using SharedPreferences and load it when app restart.